# Description of exe not showing up correctly for c# winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms exe that I create with all of the default settings.

My problem is I can't get the description to show up correctly in windows explorer.

When I browse to my file in windows explorer and go to file properties, in the General tab it says:

Description: Product

But my assemblyInfo.cs file has the following:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Product")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Product description")]
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
#endif
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Product")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2010")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

How can I get it to say:

Description: Product Description

I verified the same thing with this exe in windows xp and windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's AssemblyTitle, not AssemblyDescription.